# Social network site database development

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

How to manage social network site database perfectly?

I recently start building a social network site database below is my concept of database

Is this is correct or you suggests something else and why

1."user" table stores user details

2."posts" tables stores posts of all user with the user unique id

3."likes" table stores the likes of each posts separately with user, post and comment unique id

4."friends" tables stores the 50001 user ids one id of user and 5000 ids of his/er friends in separate column means 5001 fields is it ok ?

5."comments" table stores comment of all posts which uniques ids of user, post and comment

and all table loads some data on profile.php where user can able to post, like, comment

here is the things which profile.php file do on load

1. Shows post input box with submit button
2. Shows 10 posts in iframe
3. calculate and show likes, comments on each post

Is this is ok to count the total likes and comments default on any post? and when user click on likes or comments 
 than show him/er the list of peoples who's likes or comments on his/er post? is the above type of database handle this query ? and whats the speed of this process fast/normal/slow ? and "select" command is enough and work fine for this query?
Note: I use PHP, MySQL and JavaScript

Please accept my apologize for low formatting and weak English but i try my best

Thank you so much

Comment: 4)  **NO**!  Use one row per friendship.

Comment: @SLaks means two column one for user and one for his friends?

Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: And one column for his friend singular.

Comment: @SLaks means his/er friend is male or female right?

Comment: @SLaks your idea is really nice is to use one row per friendship i think if we use this its also easy to get mutual friends

Comment: A lot of this stuff will already be available in open source social networking systems such as Elgg (elgg.org). Have a look at that, as it will do the necessary caching for larger installations.

Comment: @halfer oh thanks let me check this :)

Comment: @DanishIqbal:i am also developing social networking app for android.I am in a bit of trouble about the structure of database.Could u help me?

Answer (score 2):

Seams more or less on target (though a very naive approach) with just a single big **NO!** on the user friends table.

```
userId | friendId
```

Should be the friends table. Just that. When you want to look for user with ID 24 friends you do a

```
SELECT friendId from user_friends_table WHERE userId = 24
```

Aside from it start it. **The only real way for you to acknowledge how you should have implemented it is to try and fail.** Over and over again.

Comment: One possible addition to the SQL above is: `select u.* from user_friends_table uft left join user u on u.id = uft.friendId`, to get info about the friends in one query.

Comment: @Frankie thank you so much and what do you say about other things in the question

Comment: @BenWerdmuller i guess your suggestion is also good but actually my knowledge is low thats why i not understand it sorry

Comment: @Danish Iqbal using my query you would get a list of all the friends of user 24, by number. So your results would be something like `1, 4, 8, 23, 34` in representation of the friends of user 24. Now with his query your are "left-joining" all the information from the user's table where `friendId` matches `userId`. Meaning that you will get all friends of user 24 with *extra* details like name, email, etc... it's the logical step. Otherwise you would need thousands of queries and would eventually kill your DB server. Do start your project as things like this will come naturally.

Comment: @Frankie got it very nice and please also advice me about the other things in my question 
thank you so much for kind favour

Comment: @Danish Iqbal your welcome. All the stuff you describe will be done sub-second. In fact, every single trivial operation will be done sub-second until you start having 10k rows or more. So my real advice is to get your hands dirty as fast as you can. You will have to iterate your app dozens of times until you get it semi-functional so you'll only really come across *real* problems when your start implementing it.